# how to serve data out of a database asqueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

We can create an array of records, and allow it to be Queryable:

```
        var entities = new[] {
            new Product{ Id = 1,Category  = "Test 1" },
            new Product{ Id = 2, Category = "Test 2" },
            new Product{ Id = 3, Category = "Another texts" },
        }.AsQueryable();
```

How do we get the same functionality if instead of querying in memory, that we go directly to a database?

The specific use case would be to expose the data via odata:

```
    public IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        // plug your entities source (database or whatever)
        var entities = (mydatabaseentity????).AsQueryable();  

        var modelManager = (IODataModelManger)HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IODataModelManger));
        var model = modelManager.GetModel(nameof(Web1));
        var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(Product), null);
        var queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, HttpContext.Request);

        return queryOptions
            .ApplyTo(entities, new ODataQuerySettings
            {
                HandleNullPropagation = HandleNullPropagationOption.True
            })
            .Cast<Product>();
    }
```

**How do we expose data out of a database, in order to make it queryable as the Product entity is above, and then allowing it to be odata-queryable?**

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? You have tagged asp.net-core and asp.net-web-api2 which are different versions of the framework.

Comment: @DavidPaquette thank you. i'm only using core, and i've updated tag!

Comment: Be careful exposing IQueryable from the database - it can leak db concerns throughout other parts of your application when they should be encapsulated in your data layer. See Repository and Specification patterns for ways to combat this.http://deviq.com/specification-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use an ORM like Entity Framework.

Assuming you have a Context defined that maps to your database.

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

then a simple query like `var products = _context.Products;` will actually return an `IQueryable` for you. The specifics of setting up Entity Framework for your project will depend on your database and what the Product class looks like but the key is that `DbSet` is itself an `IQueryable`. Likewise you could add a constraint to your query by doing something like `_context.Products.Where(p => p.Name == "SOMEVALUE");`. With Entity Framework you do not need to add `.AsQueryable()`. The value that is returned is already an `IQueryable`.

The following docs should help:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: awesome! is it easy to make these controllers allow odata querying against?

Comment: I'm not totally sure on the odata side. I don't know if OData supports Entity Framework Core.